# Angular: Click button to redirect to another page not working

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In the Market > Value page, I have a button named add, when the user clicks on this button, the user goes to another page. This page is named ajout.

Here is the structure

[image: structure]

value.component.html

```
<div class="text-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="btnAjout">Add</button>
</div>
```

value.component.ts

```js
btnAjout(): void {
   this.router.navigateByUrl('/ajout');
}
```

market-routing.module.ts

```
{
  path: 'value',
  component: ValueComponent,
},
{
  path: 'ajout', 
  component: AjoutComponent
},
```

ajout.component.html

```
<p>ajout works!</p>
```

The ajout page is not working, did I make a mistake?

Code [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-tapnwk?file=src/app/views/dashboard/views/market/views/value/value.component.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Issue 1: Unable fire `btnAjout` method**

`btnAjout` is a function. Hence with `(click)="btnAjout"`, it never trigger the `btnAjout` function.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="btnAjout">Add</button>
```

```js
btnAjout(): void {
  ...
}
```

**Solution for Issue 1**

Correct the click event.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="btnAjout()">Add</button>
```

---

**Issue 2: Incorrect routing to 'market/ajout'**

From reviewing `DashboardRoutingModule` to `MarketingRoutingModule`, (to redirect) `adjout` component's URL should be:

> /market/adjout

Instead of:

```js
this.router.navigateByUrl('/ajout');
```

**Solution for Issue 2**

Correct the url path.

```js
this.router.navigateByUrl('/market/ajout');
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-tapnwk-ezrr6j?file=src/app/views/dashboard/views/market/views/value/value.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you a lot for your explanations and your time, it works !